# Weird notation - never seen before

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, notation

I've never seen the following notation before:

[image]

What does it mean?

Example in the cost function [here](http://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2016/08/22/under-the-hood-of-the-variational-autoencoder-in.html)

Comment: from the deep learning book? which page?

Comment: Notation is just a convention -- this will need more context to decipher.

Comment: One guess is that $p_{\text{data}}$ means the empirical distribution.  It hardly matters, because the expectation of the constant $-\log 2$ is $-\log 2$, the distribution do not matter!

Comment: Looks like it means negative log two.

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: In the description of the EM algorithm on Wikipedia, people use to do the same stupid things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm. Here they write $E_{Z|X}[f(Z,X)]$ and they actually mean is the (factorization of the) conditional expectation $E[f(Z,X)|X=x]$ and I assume that they want to express something similar here... maybe it is $E[\text{log}p_{\theta}(X|Z) | X=x]$ or maybe restricted to $Z=z$?